# Error: package x.x.x is unknown, for "run-as (classname)" command on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 running Android 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet, Android 4.4.2.

As a developer, I need to be able to see my files in `/data/data/(classname)`, but I don't want to root my tablet.  Found out one can read files in `/data/data/(classname)` by using `run-as (classname)` after getting into the shell (i.e., `adb shell`), but this is giving me "package x.x.x is unknown".

Seeing, upon searching, that this is a Samsung *issue*, perhaps with this particular Android release.  Went to Samsung support chat, but the 'technical support' could not help.

Has anyone seen this issue?  TIA.

Comment: Same problem with Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (model SM-T230), which also runs on Android 4.4.2 and probably won't ever get another update.